# Python groupby function to count 2 columns of data

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have data that looks something like this:

```
+------------+-----+--------+
|    Room    | TV  | Lights |
+------------+-----+--------+
| Bedroom1   | On  | Off    |
| Bedroom2   | On  | On     |
| LivingRoom | Off | On     |
| Bedroom2   | On  | On     |
| LivingRoom | Off | Off    |
| Bedroom1   | Off | On     |
| LivingRoom | On  | On     |
| Bedroom2   | On  | On     |
| Bedroom2   | On  | On     |
| Bedroom1   | On  | Off    |
| LivingRoom | On  | On     |
+------------+-----+--------+
```

I am trying to use the pandas groupby function to count the number of on's and off's for each room.  So the output would be something like this:

```
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
|            | TV(On) | TV(Off) | Lights(On) | Lights(Off) |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
| Bedroom1   |      2 |       1 |          1 |           2 |
| Bedroom2   |      4 |       0 |          4 |           0 |
| LivingRoom |      2 |       2 |          3 |           1 |
+------------+--------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

I know you need the count function to get the number of occurrences e.g

data.groupby('Room')['TV', 'Lights'].count()

but how do i separate that into different columns for On and Off counts.  I've also tried using aggregation but cannot get it to work.

Comment: Can you post how dataframe looks like? post print(df.head(5)) Also expected result.

Comment: Sorry i'm trying to edit it to show the tables better.  Posting tables here seems to be harder than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so this actually is a groupby problem after all. First, get your df in a format more similar to your final result:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Room': df.Room, 'Lights(On)': df.Lights == 'On', 'Lights(Off)': df.Lights == 'Off'})

    Lights(Off)  Lights(On)      Room
0         True       False  Bedroom1
1        False        True  Bedroom2
2        False        True  Bedroom2


result = df2.groupby('Room').sum()


          Lights(Off)  Lights(On)
Room
Bedroom1          1.0         0.0
Bedroom2          0.0         2.0
```

Comment: How do i get it in the dataframe format above (edited the question to show the format better).  I need one dataframe with all counts.  Is that not possible from one command?

Comment: This is close but the TV columns are not included

Comment: Actually this only gives me lights(On) for each room

Comment: Ok got it.  Just needed to add 'TV(On)': df.TV == 'On', 'TV(Off)': df.TV == 'Off'.  It seems to be working now.